# How to add a widget to an EXTJS application?

Tags: extjs, widget

I downloaded a file upload widget for EXTJS and I don't know how to add it to use it in my project
The folder "UploadDialog" contains : 
  -A CSS folder : "css" 
  -An images folder : "images" 
  -A locale folder : "locale" 
  -Two javascript files : "Ext.ux.UploadDialog.js" and "Ext.ux.UploadDialog.packed.js"

How to do please
Thanx a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you just put it somewhere you can access from the page you want to include it on and then add the required references to the JavaScript and CSS files.

I tend to keep all my UX together in an UX folder.